Upper Bound for the Field of Definition of an Elliptic Surface
I've been reading Silverman's 'Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves', and am currently up to Chapter 3, focusing on Elliptic Surfaces. In this chapter, he introduces the Field of Definition of the elliptic surface, which is the smallest number field $k$ such that $E(\mathbb{C}(t)) = E(k(t))$. I know that we can find an explicit bound for the degree $[k:\mathbb{Q}]$ which depends only on the rank of $E(\mathbb{C}(t))$, since this is asked for in Exercise 3.17, as well as stated in the 1990 paper 'The field of definition of the Neron-Severi group' by Swinnerton-Dyer.
I was wondering if someone would be able to provide a reference for the result, or a step in the direction of its proof?
At this stage my main attempt has been to look at the elliptic regulator of the elliptic surface with respect to the canonical height, and the determinant of a height pairing matrix with respect to the height relative to a number field, but I have not had much success with this method.

The following references should be relevant:
Kuwata, Masato, Ramified primes in the field of definition for the Mordell-Weil group of an elliptic surface, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 116, No. 4, 955-959 (1992). ZBL0786.14010.
Kuwata, Masato, The field of definition of the Mordell-Weil group of an elliptic curve over a function field, Compos. Math. 76, No. 3, 399-406 (1990). ZBL0731.14010.
